# Getting Error login via Linkedin in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, 3rd-party-library

Hi I am using Social Login plugin in my site. I have added LinkedIn App id and Secret Key but Getting Below Error. Any one help me, which link I have to set to **Authorized Redirect URLs:** in LinkedIn Account.

[image: Lindedin Error]

If any one have idea then ask me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have added wrong return/redirect url in linkedin developer console or didn't add url. Also if you have added your local url like using ip(127.0.0.1/magento) then also its create issue with redirection.